# How to fix the limits of plt.colorbar() for every separate spectrogram plot for comparison

Tags: colorbar, spectrogram

At every epoch of training a CNN, I produce a spectrogram to monitor intermediate results. The problem is that every time the colorbar of each spectrogram changes slightly, so that the plots can not be directly comparable. How can I fix the colorbar once, so that it is used every time a new spectrogram is plotted, but without actually manipulating the values of spectrograms?

Right now, I generate the spectrograms like this:

```
for i in range(len(output_stfts)):
    S_db = librosa.amplitude_to_db(output_stfts[i], ref=np.max)
    plt.figure()
    librosa.display.specshow(S_db)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.savefig(file_name[i])
    plt.close('all')
```

And get an output (in separate files) like this

File 1
[image: Epoch 2]

File 2
[image: Epoch 3]

I would like the spectrograms to have the same colorbar without manipulating (normalizing) the spectrograms. I don't have the spectrograms beforehand, they are generated on-the-fly. Setting the limits to a fixed range e.g. [0, -50] would do. Everything that is below -50dB may be clipped to that value.